# How to put a range on an enumeration?

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

I have an assignment in which I have to use enumerations in order store letter values. The link is provided [here](https://scs.senecac.on.ca/~oop345/pages/workshops/w5.html)

I am totally clueless as to how I can use enumerations to set a range of values in a constant.

`// What I'm trying to do
enum class Letter { A+, A, B+, B, etc... }`

However, I'm already having an issue with just the '+' in the A.

Any help would be appreciated in regard to this matter

Comment: Also you can't assign a range to a enum constant. You'd have to write some code to convert ranges to constants.

Comment: If the actual character sequence "A+" is important, then you probably want to use a std::set of std::strings.

Answer (score 5):

`+` is not a legal character that can be used in that context. Use something else, such as `A_PLUS`.

```
enum class Letter { A_PLUS, A, B_PLUS, B, etc... }
```

Answer (score 0):

As HolyBlackCat said, you can't specify a range for an enumerator.  As R Sahu said, you can't use `+` in an identifier - read [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers) to learn more about that.  It's also best practice to avoid all-uppercase (with or without underscore) identifiers for anything except preprocessor macros/defines (and for single letters, template arguments).  Anyway, you can do something like this:

```
enum class Grade { a_plus, a, b_plus, b, ... };

Grade score_to_grade(int score)
{
    return score >= 90 ? Grade::a_plus :
           score >= 80 ? Grade::a :
           score >= 75 ? Grade::b_plus :
           ...
           score >= 50 ? Grade::d :
           Grade::f;
}
```

The `? :` thing is the [*conditional operator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other).  Above, it's a more concise (and once you get used to it, readable) equivalent to:

```
if (score >= 90) return Grade::a_plus;
if (score >= 80) return Grade::a;
...
```